# Height of image depends on text

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is make the background image's height change depending on the amount of text.

ex. image height is 100px and the text within that div is 150px. How would I extend the images height to 150px (or more) depending on the amount of text that was entered?

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-bg">
  <img src="img/scroll_top.gif" style="position:absolute" />
      <div class="scroll-bg-img">
        <div class="scroll-content">
        <center><img src="img/recent_news.gif" /></center>
        <div style="width:100%;margin-top:15px">
          <div style="margin-top:10px;color:black">
            <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT MORE TEXT</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-bg {
    width: 810px;
    float: right;
}

.scroll-content {
    width: 765px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.scroll-bg-img {
    background-image: url(img/scroll_bg.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 795px; 
    height: 1000px;
    margin-top: 40px; 
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Will cause the background to stretch to fit the container, but that won't be sized to the text as long as you have explicit `height` and `width` set on `.scroll-bg-img`

If you remove those, and let it be sized to the height of the text, the background image will stretch to fit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `background-size : cover` in your `.scroll-bg-img` CSS. However, not all browsers will support that. Just look it up and see what it's all about.

EDIT:

```
.scroll-bg-image {
    background-image : url("img/scroll_bg.gif");
    background-position : center center;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;
}
```

Update the background properties as such, and see how that does for you.

Comment: That seemed to have screwed up the background image. The right half of it is cut off if I add that property.

Comment: @ShadyPotato Updated. Try that out.